# MySQL showing different versions

Tags: mysql, macos, version

I feel like this question is very stupid, but it has been bothering me so much and I couldn't find an answer, so I'm gonna ask it anyway.

I'm on a Mac machine. When I run

> mysql --version

It shows that I'm on

> mysql  Ver 8.0.13 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

So I thought I'm on MySQL 8.0. But when I connect to my database and run

> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

It shows

> version   5.7.24

---

So I was wondering that

1. What version of MySQL that I'm actually on?
2. Why there are 2 different versions? Are they different products of MySQL? Will they conflict at all?

Comment: Your mac might be having multiple versions of MySQL. If you type 'mysql --version' on terminal it is referring to the location of this default installed MySQL. But the program you are using to access the database is referring to another MySQL installed in your system.
When you type 'mysql' in the terminal, the system should know from where it has to invoke the mysql program. We will define this in PATH. refer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176786/how-to-add-mysql-to-path-variable-to-resolve-mysql-command-not-found to change the path of mysql to your required mysql

Comment: what does `mysqld --version` give you?

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts here, a client talking to a server.

What you have is:

- a MySQL 8.0.13 client (mysql)
- a MySQL 5.7.24 server (mysqld)

The database is effectively on version 5.7.24.

There is no conflicts, clients and servers from different versions are compatible, as they understand the same communication protocol.